# localStorage on wp8 error

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

I have a WP8 HTML/JS app and I need to save some simple data on the local storage. It should be something very easy, but it is giving my a headache already.

I tried to call the **localStorage** in many different ways but it doesn't work. The error message I get is:
*The system cannot find the file specified.*

The strange part, is that the **sessionStorage seems to be fine**. At least I don't get any error using that object.

**Additional info:**
- The ways I called localStorage are: localStorage.setItem(), window['localStorage'], window.localStorage, etc. they all say the same message.
- I am developing a Windows Phone HTML app OS8.
- The method I call the localStorage is in $('#channels').bind('pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {...}
- The only references in the project are .Net for Windows Phone and Windows Phone.
- Some of the js libs I included are jQuery, jQuery mobile and ko.
- I am testing on both WP8 device and Emulator

I prefer not to use phoneGap and any other known db for devices, since I wouldn't like to involve interaction with the native code just to make the call to fetch and save some data.

**UPDATE 1:**
After thefrontender comment, I investigated one by one my js refs. The problem appear when I add the jqm 1.3 min. 
All js are bundled with my app. Any other suggestions?

```
$(function () {
        try {
            localStorage.setItem('aaa', 123);
            alert(localStorage.aaa);
        }
        catch (err) { alert(err.message) }
    });
```

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2427 Are all your JS assets bundled with the app or are you linking them in from the web?

Comment: all js are bundled with my app. Well, you made me wonder so I investigated one by one my js refs. The problem appear when I add the jqm 1.3 min. <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

And if you replace

```
alert(localStorage.aaa);
```

with

```
alert(localStorage.getItem('aaa');
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work. The problem is that jqm 1.3 (even 1.3.1 that I tested) disables the access to localStorage some how.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer form jQuery official forum after all.
You need to add modernizr with atleast localStorage from HTML5 section.

Add: (first or last doent matter)

as indicated in the following post too:
http://www.pksoftlab.com/?p=1073