# Windows Phone 8.1 local storage is not working

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8.1, local-storage, internet-explorer-11

I'm building a HTML5 web application and I want to use local storage.
For some reason this code is not working on Windows Phone 8.1 (Nokia Lumia 920):

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

I don't get any error in the console, but when I try to get that value from the local storage, it returns null.

Comment: Nothing [here](https://www.google.coms/search?q=localStorage.setItem+windows+phone), for example [localStorage on wp8 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914292/localstorage-on-wp8-error)

Comment: Can you post the code where you are trying to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to save a key/value inside your app scope, I think you can try the following.

first you tell the application the name of your setting:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer yourSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

save:

```
yourSettings.Values["key"] = myValue;
```

recover:

```
var myValue = yourSettings.Values["key"];
```

It works very well for me. Hope that helps you.
Best regards.